# Eclipse RCP Plugin development - Can't get new menuContribution option

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am using Eclipse 3.2. For an RCP application, I am trying to extend from org.eclipse.ui.menus. When I right-click and pick new option, "menu Contribution" isn't appearing. I only see options 'item', 'menu', 'group', 'widget' under 'New'. There is no option named "menu Contribution". Am I missing anything in target platform? If so, which jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm it can not work.

Consider the **Extension Points Reference** help from:

- [org.eclipse.ui.menus in 3.2.1](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_menus.html)

  <!ELEMENT extension (item* , menu* , group* , widget*)>
- [org.eclipse.ui.menus in 3.4 Ganymede](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_menus.html)

  <!ELEMENT extension (group* , widget* , menuContribution*)>

That is why you do not see `menuContribution`

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/images/command70.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/images/command70.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using: 
Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.4.1
Build id: M20080911-1700
I would suggest upgrading...3.2 is a little old IMHO

[image: pde-working]